# Observe interface orientation from the View

Tags: swift, key-value-observing, interface-orientation

I was using `NotificationCenter` to observe `interfaceOrientation` change by `UIApplication.willChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification`. But `UIApplication.willChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification` is now marked deprecated. It is suggested to use `viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator`, but this is the method called from the `ViewController`. I have a subclass of `UIView` that needs this internally, and Im exposing this `View` as a `framework`. I would like to be able to still maintain this functionality without the need to be explicitly called from the `ViewController`. Is there another option to achieve this directly inside `View`? I tried observing `UIWindowScene.interfaceOrientation` with KVO, but this didn't work.

```
public extension Notification.Name {
    static let willChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification = UIApplication.willChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification    
}

...

@objc private func statusBarOrientationWillChange(notification: Notification) {
    if let orientationRawValue = notification.userInfo?[UIApplication.statusBarOrientationUserInfoKey] as? Int, let orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation(rawValue: orientationRawValue) {
        configureVideoOrientation(interfaceOrientation: orientation)
        updateSceneInformation()
    }
}

...

private func initialize() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(statusBarOrientationWillChange(notification:)), name: .willChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification, object: nil)

}
```

[image]

Comment: It's marked deprecated in the Apple developer docs, but you can still use it. I don't see them obsoleting this functionality any time soon, if ever, because of how crucial it is to many applications, and the lack of a suitable alternative like you mention

Comment: Yeah I know, but it's bugging me to see this single warning in the entire project. Maybe there is some other solution, so I could adapt.

Comment: In that case, can you share more code so that if we were to copy your class into Xcode we would see the same warning?

Comment: I have added some small code samples, I can't share the whole project. But actually there is no more to it, its just a function in UIView subclass that uses UIApplication.willChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification and UIApplication.statusBarOrientationUserInfoKey

Comment: where are your last two methods located? Inside of a class that extends `UIView`?

Comment: Yes, inside this UIView subclass

Comment: I am not seeing a warning in a brand new `12.1` build target project. Can you share the warning text?

Comment: It's for iOS 13. I've added the picture

Comment: You can try posting a custom notification when the root view controller changes orientation. It's a shame Apple does not have a suitable alternative for this functionality. Good question. You should recommend it as an addition in the swift evolution git project

Comment: Yeah I could use custom notification, but this still enforces some extra work on the user of this class. Guess there might not be a perfect solution. I will probably stay with current implementation, until I can find something better. Thanks for comments.

Comment: Added an answer that might address your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It seems to only be available as a post-orientation-change notification and not a pre-orientation-change notification, but it should not produce a deprecation warning. Note that the device orientation is of the `UIDeviceOrientation` type, not the `UIInterfaceOrientation` type.

```swift
public class MyView: UIView {

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        NotificationCenter.default.
                addObserver(self, 
                            selector: #selector(deviceOrientationDidChange), 
                            name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, 
                            object: nil)
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    @objc
    private func deviceOrientationDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        guard UIDevice.current.orientation.isValidInterfaceOrientation,
              let orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation(rawValue: UIDevice.current.orientation.rawValue) 
            else { return }
        configureVideoOrientation(interfaceOrientation: orientation)
        updateSceneInformation()
    }

}
```